# Match more than once

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regex.

```
(\w+(?==\w+)|(?!==\w+)\w+)(?!\{\{)(?!.*token)(?=.*}})
```

Test string:

```
some text {{token id=foo1 class=foo2 attr1=foo3 hi=we}} more text {{token abc=xyz}} final text
```

But, this matches only `{{token abc=xyz}}` and not the `{{token id=fool class=foo2 attr1=foo3 hi=we}}`

I've already used `g` modifier.

How can I modify to match the first one also?

Comment: May this help us understand the OP's regex: https://www.debuggex.com/r/JqtTtr6qTY9os5dW.

Comment: Do you always want to match 2 of them, or do you want as many matches as possible?

Comment: Can't you simply use [`{{.*?}}`](http://regexr.com?38ih1)?

Comment: @TomFenech, I want to match all instances

Comment: @sp00m, no. I want to find all key=value pairs that follow `token` and all this should be in `{{` and `}}`

Comment: @AmitJoki You should add this explanation within your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is in line to what you are trying to do
(Replace the `.` with `[\S\s]` if you want to span lines on the downstream check)

This first sollution can't validate `{{token` exists

```
 #  /(?:(\w+)=(\w+))(?=(?:(?!{{token[ ]|}}).)*}})/

 (?:            # Next key,val pair
      ( \w+ )   # (1)
      = 
      ( \w+ )   # (2)
 )
 (?=            # Downstream, must be a }}
      (?:
           (?! {{ token [ ] | }} )
           . 
      )*
      }}            
 )
```

Perl test case

```
$/ = undef;

$str = <DATA>;

while ( $str =~ /(?:(\w+)=(\w+))(?=(?:(?!{{token[ ]|}}).)*}})/g )
{
     print "$1 = $2\n";
}

__DATA__
some text {{token id=foo1 class=foo2 attr1=foo3 hi=we}} more text {{token abc=xyz}} final text
```

Output >>

```
id = foo1
class = foo2
attr1 = foo3
hi = we
abc = xyz
```

---

This solution uses two regex's. One to grab the `{{token .. }}`, one to parse `key`=`value`

```
 # Regex 1

 {{ token \b 
 (?:
      (?! {{ | }} )
      . 
 )+
 }}

 # Regex 2

 (?:            # Next key,val pair
      ( \w+ )   # (1)
      = 
      ( \w+ )   # (2)
 )
```